# Azure WAF with Application Gateway and Custom Domains

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have set up an Application Gateway V2 with a WAF and some Web Apps.
I also have set up custom domains for the Web Apps and the listeners of the Gateway are redirecting to the Web App which belongs to the domain the Gateway is listening at.

Let's assume I want to block access from external for specific URLs of the different Web Apps (in this case containing f.e. admin or anotheradmin).
[www.webapp1.com/admin](http://www.webapp1.com/admin)
[www.webapp2.com/anotheradmin](http://www.webapp2.com/anotheradmin)

So I can configure the WAF "deny if requesturi contains admin/anotheradmin".
Setting up this rule will be global for every Web App behind the WAF.
Is there a way to set up a rule for a specific Web App or domain?

I would like to do this:
"block traffic for [www.webapp1.com](http://www.webapp1.com) if requesturi contains admin" or
"block traffic for [www.webapp2.com](http://www.webapp2.com) if requesturi contains anotheradmin"

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, instead of configuring WAF rules at the global level this can be achieved on individual Application. Create a separate listener for each domain and associate the listener to the appropriate backend pool containing the web app in order to define a WAF rule.

Created Application gateway V2 with WAF:

[image]

In Application gateway WAF policy add custom rule like below:

[image]

> Even you have global policy if you create listener specific or path specific depending upon configuration you can create waf policy and deny traffic. Usually per-site policy will be preferred than global policy, global policy as least preference.

In custom rule if you to block this access from external site you can block traffic coming from a range of IP addresses

In match type select `Ip address` match variable as `remoteaddr` keep operation as 'Not' if the operation does not contain your range, it will be denied. Only the virtual network range can be permitted everything else will be rejected.

[image]

Make sure in Waf policy to include the necessary rules and assign the policy to the listeners for the web apps.

[image]

***References:***

[Azure Web Application Firewall (WAF) v2 custom rules on Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/custom-waf-rules-overview)

[To restrict a domain from public access in Azure - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/492132/to-restrict-a-domain-from-public-access-in-azure)

Comment: Hello and thank you! So that means I have to create more than only one WAF policy if I want different rules for different backends, right? What I also tried, (and it worked) was using the Host Header.

Comment: In addition to your answer (which is correct) there should be mentioned that it will require more than one WAF policy (one for each listener or one for multiple listeners if custom rules are the same) I just tried it and it is working. I am now using one WAF policy as global and then the other WAF policies for the specific app/listener

Comment: You're correct, if you want different rules for different backends or listeners, you would need to create separate WAF policies. In your case, if you have different WAF rule requirements for different web apps or domains, you can create multiple WAF policies. One WAF policy can be used as a global policy with common rules, and additional WAF policies can be created for specific apps or listeners with their own custom rules.